# How to output each value from raw via Print or something else in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have code

```
DECLARE @UserRolesList NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Admin, Dog, BranchManager, Naid'
--DECLARE @UserRolesList NVARCHAR(MAX) = 't1, t2, t3'

DECLARE @UserRoles TABLE (Name VARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @UserRoles
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@UserRolesList, ',')

SELECT * FROM UserRole u 
              JOIN @UserRoles r ON u.Name = TRIM(r.Name)
```

And I need output each value from a row of joining result something like that `Print('Admin, ' Adminitration role ...')` and so on, how I can do this?
[image]

Comment: Please show the results you want as a *table*.  I don't get what you are asking -- why is `print` needed instead of just using the result set?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want the roles concatenated together for each user:

```
SELECT u.user_id, STRING_AGG(u.name, ', ') as roles
FROM UserRole u JOIN
     @UserRoles r
     ON u.Name = TRIM(r.Name)
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```